# Adding elements in an ArrayList together

Tags: java, arrays

If I have an `ArrayList` like:

```
[20,5,7,9]
```

and I want to add `20+5` and `7+9` and create a new value to replace the two I added together so I would create a `new ArrayList` like:

```
[25,16]
```

How would I go about doing this? Would I just create an `int` result and declare a new `ArrayList`, then replace the values into the `new ArrayList`? Or can I just edit the `ArrayList` as it computes the value?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it right in the original `ArrayList`:

Pseudo-code:

```
for(the next two elements)
   get the sum
   set the first element to the sum
   delete the second
```

Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < (list.size() - 1); i++)  {
   int sum = list.get(i) + list.get(i + 1);
   list.set(i, sum);
   list.remove(i + 1);

   //i is incremented by ONE, because the element 
   //after i was just deleted.
}
```

Comment: Changed for-loop terminator, to prevent an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when there's an odd number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void main(String []args){
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(20, 5, 7, 9));
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i=0; i< list.size(); i++){
  if (i % 2 == 1) {
    continue;
  }
  list2.add(list.get(i) + (list.size() > i + 1 ? list.get(i+1) : 0 ));
}
for(Integer it :  list2) {            
    System.out.println(it);
}

 }
```

}

Comment: Now I guess will solve your problem... it is really compiling! ;)

Comment: I agree, It would crash. I fixed that now.

Comment: I think the ternary should be returning the remaining element's value, instead of just zero.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following:

```
...
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
try{
    for (int i=0; i<source.size();i=i+2)
        result.add(source.get(i)+source.get(i+1));
    }
catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    }
```

(assuming 'source' is your original list)

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Note that this will crash if you have an odd number of elements in your list (it's a good answer, but just keep that in mind)

Comment: You are correct good sir, I don't think the OP would plan on running with odd numbered item lists, but have fixed it just in case.

Comment: I wouldn't call swallowing an exception "fixed".

Comment: @aliteralmind or it could be to have the loop terminate at source.size()-1

Comment: well, I mean it's really up to the OP how they would want to handle the use case of an odd numbered item list, I'm not going to make that decision for him...

Comment: Using exceptions as a replacement for logic is just plain bad practice.

Comment: I'm so angry I could spit. Ptooey.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would create new array and put the new value into the array. I think this way is better. To add 20 to 5 you just call out the first element and add to the second element and then put it into your new array. Do the same for the 7+9, the key is that make sure you call out the right element.